# What is DAP IDCODE for the CPU Motorola 68hc11?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cpu, jtag, bypass

Does anyone know any of the following info for the CPU Motorola 68hc11?

- DAP IDCODE
- BYPASS COMMAND
- DAP ABORT Command

Comment: Wouldn't that require it to support JTAG first?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's on board that has a JTAG connector to it.

Comment: Okay, but that MCU doesn't support JTAG regardless.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I didn't know that. Thanks. You can add your comment as an answer so we can mark this as an answered question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Motorola 68HC11 family doesn't support JTAG. Any JTAG connector on a board with a chip from that family is for coprocessors or glue logic on that board, but not for that MCU itself.